# Cannot group strings correctly if use IEnumerable<T>.GroupBy in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's assume that I have the following files

```
File_1.txt
File_2.txt
File_1_Over.txt
File_2_Item.txt

File_1_Over.bat
File_1_Over_test.bat
File_2_Standard.bat
File_2_Item_Standard.bat
```

I want to group `txt` files with their `bat` files.

I wrote the code like:

```
List<string> val1 = new List<string> {
          "File_1.txt","File_2.txt","File_1_Over.txt","File_2_Item.txt","File_1_Over.bat",
            "File_1_Over_test.bat","File_2_Standard.bat","File_2_Item_Standard.bat"
        };

        val1.GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));

        foreach(string i in val1){
            Console.WriteLine(i);   
        }
```

It displays:

```
File_1.txt
File_2.txt
File_1_Over.txt
File_2_Item.txt
File_1_Over.bat
File_1_Over_test.bat
File_2_Standard.bat
File_2_Item_Standard.bat
```

That's not OK. That seems with `Sort`. I want to display like this:

```
File_1.txt
File_1_Over.txt
File_1_Over.bat
File_1_Over_test.bat
File_2.txt
File_2_Standard.bat
File_2_Item.txt
File_2_Item_Standard.bat
```

I wrote the code on http://compilr.com (see my code live : https://compilr.com/djsonique4ever/testproj/main.cs)

Anyway, I want in first occurence to be a TXT file not BAT.

Comment: `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<>`, but you are throwing it away. See if it works better if you do `val1 = val1.GroupBy(...);` instead. (Not writing this up as a proper answer because I don't have time to verify it right now.)

Comment: You're grouping instead of sorting. Is it really what you want to do?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `val1 = val1.GroupBy(...);` wouldn't compile

Comment: @L.B So `var val2 = val1.GroupBy()`? Or put it into the initial `var1` assignment.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov: What's happens if first file appears as BAT ? I want to be first the TXT

Comment: You have many problems in your code: 1) you throw away the result from the grouping 2) `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` wont group `File_1_Over.bat` by `File_1` for example

Comment: I must be missing something - cannot see what is wrong with .Sort

Comment: Here's bat first, txt second http://ideone.com/fcYr7g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really make sure it comes out as you want it, you could do it like [that](http://ideone.com/KbhaGo):

```
var val = val1
    .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)) //group by filename
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key); //here's the "Sort"

foreach (var group in val)
{
    var q = group.OrderByDescending(f => Path.GetExtension(f)); //order the filenames for outputting
    foreach (var f in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

I'd reconsider your task though and perhaps make it clear why you want to exactly that

Update: in case you really need the grouping. Without the grouping you may find nice answers below that are much shorter.

Comment: Wouldn't `val1.OrderBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
                    .ThenByDescending(f => Path.GetExtension(f))` be easier?

Comment: You have to order within groups. Your ThenByDescending would be ordering groups themselves. An one-line way would be to control what to select into groups while ordering that

Comment: Dmitry, Strange since it worked when I tested it. (Also see there is no GroupBy)

Comment: I see what you mean, you wouldn't group at all. Sure, then it's the simplest form. It's not clear though whether Snake Eyes needs the grouping at all

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to do is that sorting them:

```
val1.Sort();
```

If you want to sort with your own rule, let write your compare function like this:

```
static int Compare2String(string a, string b)
{
    var name_a = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a);
    var name_b = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(b);
    if (name_a.Equals(name_b))
    {
        var ext_a = Path.GetExtension(a);
        var ext_b = Path.GetExtension(b);
        return ext_b.CompareTo(ext_a);
    }
    return name_a.CompareTo(name_b);
}
```

And call Sort function like that:

```
val1.Sort((new Comparison<string>(Compare2String)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are throwing away the result returned by the `GroupBy` method. This method doesn't modify the `IEnumerable<T>` in-place, it returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` instead:

```
var val1 = new List<string> 
{
    "File_1.txt","File_2.txt","File_1_Over.txt","File_2_Item.txt","File_1_Over.bat",
    "File_1_Over_test.bat","File_2_Standard.bat","File_2_Item_Standard.bat"
};

var result = val1.GroupBy(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    foreach (var file in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```